# Can a Syrian citizen living outside the US invest in US market?

Tags: investing, international, international-trading

My sister lives in Damascus Syria. She wants to put her savings (in US dollars) in an ETF or mutual fund like VTSAX. So here are the questions:

1. Is there a brokerage firm that caters to people like that in the middle East and Africa? if not :
2. Can a US resident open an account on behalf of a forign person?
3. What sort of tax does a foreigner investor have to pay on short/long term gain?

Comment: You might give Interactive Brokers a call or e-mail.